# Why do I get Operation 'cond/IsVariableInitialized' has been marked as not fetchable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So when I run the below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

tensor_a = K.variable([])
def return_zero():
    return 0
def get_mean():
    return K.get_value(K.tf.reduce_mean(tensor_a))

is_equal = tf.equal(tf.size(tensor_a), 0)
r = tf.cond(is_equal, return_zero, get_mean)

print(r)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Operation 'cond/IsVariableInitialized' has been marked as not fetchable.
```

However, if this code is run, there is no error. What gives?

```
tensor_a = K.variable([])

print(
  K.get_value(
    tf.cond(
      tf.equal(tf.size(tensor_a), 0), 
      lambda : tf.constant(0.0), lambda: tf.reduce_mean(tensor_a)
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

tf.cond takes operations as lambda functions.

Please read https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4094 for more details on it